# How to hide/show part of the text by button tap

Tags: swift, xcode, button, autolayout, uitextfield

I have long text in UILabel and button, which could hide/show this text.
But I don't understand how to realize this.

My text is located in a cell. Button in next cell.

At the first time I need to show only three lines of text.

[image]

Comment: Change the line limit from 3 to 0 and let the autolayout do the magic

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini thank you! It's works. But how to reload my view after button tapped?

Comment: Assuming you’re using a table view, call the table view’s `
reloadRows(at:with:)` and pass it the `IndexPath`(s) of the cells you want to reload. (You need to record the fact that your cell should be displaying more than 3 lines of text in your model somehow, and have cellForRowAt configure the cell to show > 3 lines of text. )